# Scientific Notation in Handsontable

Tags: javascript, d3.js, handsontable

Looking for a way to display scientific notation (`12000 = 1.2e+4`) with `Handsontable v0.33.0`

I've found the documentation for formatting numbers in [Numbro](http://numbrojs.com/format.html) but it seems geared towards displaying statistics and currency (ie. `1230974` using `format: '0.0a'` gives `1.2m`)

Ideally I'd like the number to be formatted the way [d3-format](https://github.com/d3/d3-format) handles this

```
var value = 1230974
var formattedValue = d3.format(".3")(value)
console.log(formattedValue) // expected value: "1.23e+6"
```

Comment: What about using `Number(value).toExponential()` to get formatted string, and then use it in [custom rendeder](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.35.0/demo-custom-renderers.html)?

Comment: I'm trying out some workaround now that uses both of those suggestions. Trouble is, I don't want Exp all the time, only when it makes sense to use it. I'll see what I come up with

Comment: If you have custom renderer then you can transform number to string in any way you want. For example you may have "smart" approach like using exponential format only if number of trailing zeroes is greater than number of leading digits. Like 12300 remains but 1230000 is 1.23e+6.  See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/6rjne8sk/

Comment: Getting a custom renderer to work was harder than I thought because I'm using VueJS and [vue-handsontable-official](https://github.com/handsontable/vue-handsontable-official).  

The issue there is in registering the custom renderer because I can't think how to access the Handsontable instance used inside the Vue component.  

Found a workaround using the comments on [this github issue](https://github.com/handsontable/vue-handsontable-official/issues/27) but looks like I'll have to fork the repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with following [@andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2151810/andy)'s advice and reading up on Handsontable [Custom renderers](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.33.0/demo-custom-renderers.html)

```
var sensibleNumericRenderer = (hotInstance, td, row, column,
                               prop, value, cellProperties) => {
  Handsontable.renderers.BaseRenderer.apply(this, arguments);

  let prec = 4
  let str

  var val = Handsontable.helper.stringify(value)

  if(val === "") {
    str = val
  }
  else {
    val = +val //convert to Number

    //convert numbers that are too large or too small
    if(val !== 0 && (Math.abs(val) > 1e4 || Math.abs(val) < 1e-2)) {
      //truncate to 4 significant figures then convert to scientific notation
      str = Number.parseFloat(val.toPrecision(prec)).toExponential()
    }
    else {
      // works nicely for small integers or larger decimal fractions
      str = d3.format(`.${prec}`)(val)
    }
  }
  td.innerHTML = str
  return td
}

Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer("sensibleNumeric", sensibleNumericRenderer)
```